# tableview height not updating inside superview

Tags: ios

[i am designing layouts as shown in image . issue is when i am adding entries in leavedetailtableview table view height remains as it is and innerview1 height is also not changing. i tried tableviewlayout and innerviewlayout but can't fixed the issue. anyone any help please suggest where i am doing mistake.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSHZL.png)

[image]

i am updating height of table view as below:

```
 self.leaveDetailTableView.rowHeight = 150;

self.leaveDetailTableViewHeightLayout.constant = [AppStateManager sharedInstance].totalDays * self.leaveDetailTableView.rowHeight ;

CGFloat height = [AppStateManager sharedInstance].totalDays * self.leaveDetailTableView.rowHeight;

CGRect tableFrame = self.leaveDetailTableView.frame;

tableFrame.size.height = height;

CGFloat newHeight = self.innerView1.frame.size.height + tableFrame.size.height;

self.leaveDetailTableView.frame = tableFrame;

[self.leaveDetailTableView setNeedsDisplay];

self.innerView1HeightLayout.constant = newHeight;

CGFloat combinedHeight =  newHeight + self.innerView2.frame.size.height + self.innerView3.frame.size.height + self.innerView4.frame.size.height + self.applyLeaveBtn.frame.size.height;

_contentViewHeightLayout.constant = combinedHeight;

[self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];

[self.leaveDetailTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

The table view is a scroll view itself. The intent for using tableviews should be, presenting the user more data than the screen can display. Users scroll through table views. If your AppStateManager returns 30, your table view would be 4500 in height. Plus, the table view will itself never scroll and use the most possible memory. Is that really what you want?

Instead, you should consider to display a table view that is as large as the screen and mix various kinds of cells that display buttons, text and images - however you need it.

1. Have you tried to deactivate Autolayout?
2. You don't need to assign the table view's row height on each reload. Instead you may return the row height from the dataSource's (or the delegate??) corresponding method for each row separately.
3. You don't need to call [setNeedsDisplay]. You only need this call if you have implemented -drawRect and want Cocoa/UIKit to call this method again.

Comment: as per my requirement i have to add data to table view so view size will be increased and after some event table size should be as earlier size i.e. 0 and view size should also have the earlier size i.e. view size expand and shrink according to table view data

Comment: Well then, you're calling layoutIfNeeded, which will cause the autolayout constraints to be applied. I think it just resets everything to - guess what - "auto". You must either manipulate the autolayout constraints or disable autolayout.

Comment: you can update hight by making its constraints by programatically because you set its hight fixed when you add its constrants.